# how to show PDF raw data in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf

I have a URL where I can download a PDF, but I cannot use something like:

```
[myWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

since this link will send out some challenges...

However, I managed to get the PDF raw data `NSURLConnection`(to be exact, I can get the data in the delegate method:

```
(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data).
```

And then I want to know, how I can show this PDF? Does anyone has any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do not really get the problem you have with loadRequest, but if you need a high-powered PDF-Engine (dunno from your request ;)) try PSPDFKit (commercial though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made my own, pdf download class, but this is the bits you'll need. In the .h of the class. Declare:

```
NSMutableData *_data;
NSString *pdfPath;
```

Also subclass the delegates for the connection

```
<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate>
```

Then in the implementation file, in `- viewDidLoad`:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pdfName.pdf"];
```

The `connection:didReceiveData:` method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if(!_data) _data = [[NSMutableData data]init];
    [_data appendData:data];
    progressView.progress =  ((float) [_data length] / (float) downloadSize);
}
```

The `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

        unsigned char byteBuffer[[_data length]];
        [_data getBytes:byteBuffer];
        [_data writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];

}
```

So when it receives data, it builds up the _data, then when it finishes it writes it to the path. Make sure the connection delegate is set to `self`.

After that, you can open the path to the PDF as you did before.

Comment: do you also know how can I wait till the PDF is generated, since these are asynchronous URLCONNECTION calls?

Comment: sure, the connectiondidfinish is when the pdf has finished downloading. If you have more than one at the same time, you need to have different pdfPaths otherwise, you will overwrite the file. If you do have more than one at the same time, the easiest way to set the tag of the connection when you declare it. i.e. [theConnection setTag:1]; Then you can on the connectiondidfinish, check the tag i.e. if (connection.tag == 1) {...}

Comment: Alternatively, you can make a pdf download class like mine lol. I give  it a pdf name and url and it will go off and download the pdf and put it in the documents path.

Comment: [theConnection setTag:1]; this is not correct - NSURLCONNECTION has not such a method. But what I did was to compare like this: [theConnection isEqual:myConnection]